# Windows 8.1 stuck in a boot loop says boot device unknown

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, usb, reset

I have a Digiland DL808w 7" tablet running Windows 8.1, I recently forgot my password and decided to erase the whole tablet. After erasing the tablet got stuck in a boot loop. Now it only shows the startup screen and then says boot device unknown. How do I reload Windows on my device using a USB flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

**What you could try the next time you lose your password**

You could create a Microsoft account and set a password there. Then make sure your tablet device is connected to the internet and enter you Microsoft account password. In case you forget that password you can go the Microsoft live site and simply set a new one.

**How to resolve your problem**

Creating a live USB-Stick is easy if you have a Windows .iso-file.
You can get one of these in the Microsoft Dream Spark shop.

If you have the image use one of the following utilities:

- Rufus (on Windows)
- UnetBootIn (on Windows)
- usb-creator (on Linux, graphical interface)
- dd (on Linux, command line interface utiltiy)

The process should be straightforward. If any questions arise or problems occur feel free to comment.